# White space at the bottom of the browser only on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

EDIT: **Check to see if you have any unwanted plugins installed. The issue was solved by removing a Google Chrome plugin called 'Slick Savings'.**

The sticky footer is working fine on both Firefox and Safari but when I open it in Google Chrome it has a small amount of white space under the footer.

The footer uses a relative position because every time I try to use absolute positioning it ends up in the middle of the page.

What should I do to get rid of this? I've tried overflow:hidden, bottom:0, padding-bottom:0

Here is the markup:

**HTML**

```
<html>

  <body>

   <div class ="wrapper">

     <div class ="content">
       Page content!
     </div>

   </div>

     <div class ="footer">
       Footer content!
     </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-family:'Droid Serif', serif;
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
  max-width:60em;
  height:100%;
  padding-bottom:16em;
  overflow:auto;
}

.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:14em;
  background-color:#F5F0E7;
  border-top:4px solid #E6DAC3;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:-14em;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle

Comment: When I try it in this fiddle atleast it work http://jsfiddle.net/cfj6quLq/ but if you to position: absolute; bottom: 0; it shouldnt come up in the middle anyway, have you tried that?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in Chrome 42 (just updated this morning). Maybe it was a bug that has recently been fixed? Which version shows the problem?

Comment: @DasBeasto Yeah I've tried position:absolute with bottom:0 and my content goes to the middle of the page

Comment: @AustinMullins I'm using Google Chrome 41.0.2. In my preferences it says that I am up to date. Here is what it looks like right now: http://i.imgur.com/Gr6PVPe.png

Comment: @AustinMullins The small silver part at the bottom of the footer being the white space im talking about (not the large amount under the picture)

Comment: It looks like there is an element with a shadow or background image beneath just before the closing `</body>` tag. Please share the complete html in the Fiddle.

Comment: Its strange that there is a silver part in the first place, if it was simply not touching the bottom it should be empty white beneath it. It kind of looks like a drop shadow but your CSS shows none given. Are you sure you didnt put shadow inline somewhere or make a background image of some sort?

Comment: @Kay Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cp55n55x/

Comment: @DasBeasto Yeah that actually only came up when I took a screenshot and posted it in in imgur. In the google chrome browser its just white space. I posted a full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cp55n55x/

Comment: Could it be you're using some sort of browser plugin?

Comment: @Kay That was it! I had some random extension on called "Slick Savings" and it was causing the white space. Thank you so much!